How to determine the optimal exploitation-exploration trade off for a fixed number of objective function evaluations
In Bayesian optimization, we guess the next sampling point by finding $x = \textrm{argmax}_x \alpha(x)$, where $\alpha(x)$ is the acquisition function. For simplicity, let us consider the upper confidence bound (UCB) acquisition function: $\alpha(x)=\mu(x) + \sqrt\beta \sigma(x)$, where $\mu(x)$ is the usual mean and $\sigma(x)$ denotes the usual square root of the variance. Here, $\beta$ is of course the dimensionless parameter ($\beta\geq0$) that tunes the trade off between exploration (high $\beta$) and exploitation (low $\beta$).
Suppose I have a computational or experimental budget of $N$ evaluations of the objective function. Is there an algorithm or heuristic for setting $\beta$ as a function of $N$?

Srinivas et al's 2010 paper Gaussian Process Optimization in the Bandit Setting is one foundational paper introducing the GP-UCB framework which is often referenced when discussing $\beta$ scheduling in Bayesian optimization. They provided theoretical analysis for the choice of $\beta$ and suggest scaling $\beta$ with a kind of logarithm schedule heuristic which is optimal in terms of regret bounds.

We formalize this task as a multiarmed bandit problem, where the payoff function
is either sampled from a Gaussian process (GP) or has low RKHS norm... In our experiments on real sensor data, GP-UCB compares favorably with other heuristical GP optimization approaches... Theorem 2... $β_t=2\log(t^22π^2/(3δ)) + 2d\log(t^2dbrp\sqrt(\log(4da/δ)))$.

Considering evaluations budget bounded up by your fixed $N$, you can simply scale the above suggested schedule with $t/N$ or $\log(t+1)/\log(N+1)$ heuristically.

Thank you for the answer. So, $\beta_t$ is a dynamic variable and your suggestion is that it increases as $\beta_t \sim t/N$?

@JulianOng I've also submitted to correct your nonstandard notation for UCB acquisition function, see reference here.

Thank you for the correction.

@JulianOng your computational budget $N$ is similar to a normalization denominator of probability as the simplest analogy for such a heuristic like $t/N$, not much real involvement with any schedule's detailed mathematical form, but to simply prevent over exploration with finite budget arm pulls intuitively. Hope this clarifies your lingering concern.

just to be clear. As the number of sampling ($t$) increases, an increasing $\beta_t \sim t/N$ would favor more exploration as more of the budget is used up, right?

Actually it's the opposite, exploration intuitively should be favored in the early stage. Note after each evaluation the GP will update both its posterior mean and variance including all previous chosen points analytically via the usual RBF or Matern kernels. This means $σ(x)$ in above acquisition function decreases (much faster comparatively than the $β_t$'s slow log increase) as evaluations pass for all points, so overall $α(x)$ discourages exploration over $t$ for all points, so that it can finally arrive at the optimum $x$ with the largest mean arm as GP surrogate for the true objective.

@JulianOng Srinivas's $\beta(t)$ schedule result of $log(t^2)$ recommended here is proved to be better in terms of regret under UCB than the usual $logt$ heuristic schedule. So now hope this completely clarifies your any lingering issue.
